# Implement the inhertited IDisposable pattern with no CA warnings

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I am dealing with following case. I have a base class that have the IDisposable pattern, it means that it have the `public virtual Dispose()` method and the `protected virtual Dispose(bool)` method. But I am not able to implement this patter in the derived class in such way that I will not receive any CA warnings. Please consider following example:

```
public class UtilizeClass : IDisposable
{
    private MyData data;

    public UtilizeClass()
    {
        data = new MyData();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        data.Dispose(); // Cannot use Dispose(bool) because it is protected.
    }
}

public class MyData : Base, IDisposable
{
    // Here we have some managed resources that must be disposed.

    // How to implement the pattern?
}

public class Base : IDisposable
{
    public virtual void Dispose() { }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) { }
}
```

All the time I receive contradictory CA warnings in the `MyData` class. For example: delete the Dispose() and move it logics to Dispose(bool).

Thank you very much for answer and help.

Comment: can you show more of `MyData`?

Comment: Is `Base` your own class, or one from a third party?

Comment: Do you *really* need to use the `Dispose(bool)` method, typically this is only really needed if you actually have unmanaged resources that need to be released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base class shouldn't have `void Dispose()` be virtual, it should be implemented and invoke the virtual `void Dispose(bool disposing)` as part of its implementation.

For more detail, and an alternate API that's slightly clearer, check out:

http://haacked.com/archive/2005/11/18/acloserlookatdisposepattern.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If `Base` is your own class, then don't implement this anti-pattern.

The two-fold dispose (one if disposing is true, one if its false) is used when a class contains both managed resources that must be disposed (e.g. a Stream object that should have it's own `Dispose` called) and unmanaged resources that must be cleaned-up.

This is a bad idea. Instead have all your classes fit into one or two categories:

A. Classes with only unmanaged resources. Ideally only one per class:

```
public sealed class HandlesUnmanaged : IDisposable
{
  private IntPtr _someUnmanagedHandleOfSomeKind;
  public string DoSomething(string someParam)
  {
    // your useful code goes here;
    // make it thin, non-virtual and likely to be inlined
    // if you need to extend functionality, but it in a
    // containing Disposable class, not a derived class.
  }
  private void CleanUp()
  {
    //your code that cleans-up someUnmanagedHandleOfSomeKind goes here
  }
  public void Dispose()
  {
    CleanUp();
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);//finaliser not needed now.
  }
  ~HandlesUnmanaged()//not called if already disposed
  {
    CleanUp();
  }
}
```

Ideally you won't even need any classes like this, but use `SafeHandle` which does that for you.

B. Classes with one or more managed resources that need to be disposed:

```
public class NoUnmanaged : IDisposable
{
  private HandlesUnmanaged _likeAbove;
  private Stream _anExampleDisposableClass;
  public virtual void Dispose()
  {
    _likeAbove.Dispose();
    _anExampleDisposableClass.Dispose();
  } 
  /* Note no finaliser, if Dispose isn't called, then _likeAbove's
  finaliser will be called anyway. All a finaliser here would do is
  slow things up and possibly introduce bugs.
  */
}
public class DerivedNoUnManaged : NoUnmanaged
{
  Stream _weMayOrMayNotHaveAnotherDisposableMember;
  public override void Dispose()
  {
    //note we only need this because we have
    //another disposable member. If not, we'd just inherit
    //all we need.
    base.Dispose();
    weMayOrMayNotHaveAnotherDisposableMember.Dispose();
  }
}
```

In all, we've either got simple unmanaged-owning classes that do the same thing in their `Dispose()` and their finaliser, except the former calls `GC.SuppressFinalize`, or we've got simple non-unmanaged-owning classes that just `Dispose()` everything they need to dispose, including a call to `base.Dispose()` if necessary, and don't have finalisers. No needs to split off the logic into two types within the same class. No risk of finalisers calling something that's been finalised, or forcing more than necessary into the finalisation queue.

And ideally, you never even do the first type at all. Just the second type.

If you're forced into it by inheriting from another party's class, then just do:

```
public MyClass : Base
{
  Stream _forExample;
  public override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if(disposing)
    {
      _forExample.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
  }
}
```

Don't handle the `disposing == false` case yourself, because don't have unmanaged resources mixed in there.

Comment: There should almost certainly only be one virtual dispose method.  If one does not wish to have a public method named `Dispose()`, then the virtual method should almost certainly be `protected void Dispose(bool)`, with the Boolean effectively being a dummy parameter to change the signature.  Otherwise, there are arguments in favor of having parameterless `Dispose()` be the virtual cleanup method, or in having it simply chain to virtual `Dispose(bool)`.  Since the only classes which should directly hold unmanaged resources (rather than managed resources which encapsulate them) are...

Comment: ...those which are designed from the ground up to serve that purpose, one shouldn't expect `Dispose(false)` to do anything except maybe log that it was called.  BTW, the non-virtual `Dispose` should probably call `GC.SuppressFinalize()`.  Derived classes should not add cleanup finalizers, but might legitimately add "alarm" finalizers.  Putting the `SuppressFinalize` at the end of the non-virtual method will ensure it doesn't get called until after all derived-class disposal is complete.

Comment: Why would one not want a public method called `Dispose()`? The only effect I can see is it makes it more likely that a user of the class might not realise it was disposable, and hence not dispose it.

Comment: If I were designing the Framework, I would probably never have even suggested that any class should implement `IDisposable` without a public `Dispose` method; I certainly do not like the notion of having a method called `Close` which is synonymous with `IDisposable.Dispose` but not having a public `Dispose` method, but Microsoft does that sort of thing in parts of the framework.  A more defensible situation for implementing `IDisposable.Dispose` without a public `Dispose` method would be in the case where a class implements an interface which inherits `IDisposable` but does not...

Comment: ...require any disposal action itself (some implementations of `IEnumerable<T>` are like that).  If sealed class `WizzleCollection<T>.Enumerator` doesn't do anything in `IDisposable.Dispose`, one may not feel a need to particularly encourage callers who know that an object is a `WizzleCollection<T>.Enumerator` to call `Dispose` on it, even though someone who received such an object by calling `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` would be expected to call `Dispose` (since they wouldn't know whether the thing they'd receive would actually require disposal or not).

Comment: In any case, chaining a protected virtual `Dispose` method from a non-virtual one does allow one to defer `GC.SuppressFinalize` until after all derived-class disposal is complete; that may be a good thing even if no derived classes will add finalizers for any purposes other than logging.

Answer (score 0):

The base class should have a `public void Dispose()` (non-virtual) that calls `Dispose(true)`.

The derived class should simply override `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)`.